# How to Add & Remove class name to parent Div with out ternary operator in react?

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to add "landing" class to a <Container tag only when Overview/Tab1 is active I have used ternary operator but the repetition of code is disappointing, Is there any way to get same output to load "landing" class with out repeating   tag and its code?

```
{active === "tab1" ? (
        <Container fluid className="p-0 py-3 containerMain landing">...</Container> : <Container  fluid className="p-0 py-3 containerMain ">...</Container>)}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-benji-j3f9xl?file=/src/Overview.js

Comment: Might I suggest [Code Review @ StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this question?

Comment: @jsN00b when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because [the code is not embedded directly](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3653#3653).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating the whole element, you can just use the ternary in the className attribute using string interpolation.

```
<Container fluid className={`p-0 py-3 containerMain ${active === "tab1" ? 'landing' : ''}`}>...</Container>
```